# make: *** [memcache.lo] Error 1

Tags: php, session, xampp, memcached

when I trying  to install memcache on xampp using this commands

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/memcache-3.0.8.tgz

tar xf memcache-3.0.8.tgz

cd memcache-3.0.8

/opt/lampp/bin/phpize


./configure --enable-memcache --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config


make && make install


/opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

i get error after this line

make && make install

the full error message

> /bin/bash /memcache-3.0.8/libtool --mode=compile cc
>   -I/opt/lampp/include/php -I. -I/memcache-3.0.8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/memcache-3.0.8/include -I/memcache-3.0.8/main -I/memcache-3.0.8 -I/opt/lampp/include/php -I/opt/lampp/include/php/main -I/opt/lampp/include/php/TSRM -I/opt/lampp/include/php/Zend -I/opt/lampp/include/php/ext -I/opt/lampp/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /memcache-3.0.8/memcache.c -o memcache.lo   cc -I/opt/lampp/include/php -I. -I/memcache-3.0.8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC
>   -I/memcache-3.0.8/include -I/memcache-3.0.8/main -I/memcache-3.0.8 -I/opt/lampp/include/php -I/opt/lampp/include/php/main -I/opt/lampp/include/php/TSRM -I/opt/lampp/include/php/Zend -I/opt/lampp/include/php/ext -I/opt/lampp/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /memcache-3.0.8/memcache.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/memcache.o In file included from
>   /memcache-3.0.8/php_memcache.h:34:0,
>                    from /memcache-3.0.8/memcache.c:30: /memcache-3.0.8/memcache_pool.h:45:47: fatal error:
>   ext/standard/php_smart_str_public.h: No such file or directory
>
> ## include "ext/standard/php_smart_str_public.h"
>
> ```
>                                            ^ compilation terminated. Makefile:193: recipe for target 'memcache.lo' failed make:
> ```
>
> *** [memcache.lo] Error 1

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I am facing the same issue with version 2.0.7 and 3.0.4